# In how many ways we could put balls into boxes?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

In how many ways we could put $n+5$ indistinguishable balls into $n$ distinguishable boxes and at least $2$ boxes have to be empty?

This is my answer: ${n}\choose{2} $$\cdot$$ {n+5+n-2-1}\choose{n+5}$
because first of all we have to choose $2$ empty boxes and after that we put $n+5$ balls into $n-2$ boxes. Is it correct?

Comment: How many balls are there? In the first sentence you say $n+1$ balls, but later it changes to $n+5$ balls.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland n+5! Sorry for that!

Comment: You will be overcounting, e.g. if boxes 1-2 is one combo kept empty, box 3 may be another empty box, but boxes 1-3 and 2-3 will again figure as initial empty combos.

Comment: **Hint:** How many ways can you put the  $n+5$ balls in the remaining $n-2$ boxes *with no empty boxes*?

Answer (score 3):

$\textbf{Hint}$:

First count the number of ways to distribute the balls without any restrictions,

and then subtract the number of distributions with

A) no empty box$\;\;$  and $\;\;$B) exactly one empty box.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to sum up using [Theorem 1 of stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) for $2$ through $(n-1)$ empty boxes

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} {n\choose k}{n+5-1\choose n-k-1}$$

but user84413's approach is more efficient.

Comment: You get an identity by equating both ;-)